# I need help making Lowest price grocery program in Java

Tags: java

My code below

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class main {
    public int finalcost;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int totalAdd = 0;
        boolean done = false;
        // to store specific properties ex item size and price
        HashMap<String, String> specificPropsMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

        // stores an array list of all the sizes and price
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> propsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // the item list stores the name of the item as the KEY and item size and price
        // as data
        HashMap<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> itemsMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>();

        // this stores the service name than the cost.this is the one we will be adding
        // too after getting the data;
        HashMap<String, Integer> cartMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("PA2.txt"));
        String line = br.readLine();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            // stores the data base on commas
            String[] fields = line.split(",");
            String serviceName = fields[0];
            String fileName = fields[1];
            String cost = fields[2];

            if (specificPropsMap.containsKey(serviceName)) {
                // do nothing
            } else {
                specificPropsMap.put(serviceName, null);
            }
            // gets the file name from the first reader
            BufferedReader brCVS = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
            String lineCVS = brCVS.readLine();
            while ((lineCVS = brCVS.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] cvsFields = lineCVS.split(",");
                String brandName = cvsFields[0];
                String nameItem = cvsFields[1];
                String itemSize = cvsFields[2];
                String itemPrice = cvsFields[3];

                // check if itemname is in specificPropsMap
                if (specificPropsMap.containsKey(cvsFields[1])) {
                    // do nothing
                } else {
                    specificPropsMap.put(itemSize, nameItem);
                }

                propsList.add(specificPropsMap);

                if (itemsMap.containsKey(nameItem)) {
                    // do nothing
                } else {
                    itemsMap.put(nameItem, null);
                }

            } // end inner while loop

            int stringCosttoInt = Integer.parseInt(cost.trim());
            if (cartMap.containsKey(serviceName)) {
                // do nothing
            } else {
                cartMap.put(serviceName, stringCosttoInt);
            }
        } // end outer while loop

        System.out.println("Welcome to Assisgnment two app");

        while (done == false) {

            System.out.println("Enter the item you are looking for or enter done check out: ");

            String key = input.nextLine(); // use key to find if item is in the itemsMap;
            if (key == "done") {
                done = true;
            } else {
                if (itemsMap.containsKey(key)) {
                    System.out.println("Enter the Size you want :");
                    // now check for the item name, than size, if not return item not there;
                    int sizeKey = input.nextInt(); // use key to find item in the area
                    if (itemsMap.containsValue(specificPropsMap.containsKey(sizeKey))) {

                        System.out.println("How many of " + key + " do you want:");
                        int numOfProduct = input.nextInt();

                        // add it to the cart;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("No: " + sizeKey + " in the system");

                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("No item by the name of: " + key + " in the system");
                }
            }
        }
        br.close();

        input.close();
    }

}
```

Question: How do I set the user input to search the item class to return the lowest total cost. The user enters item name, size and the amount. I know in storing the name in item, but I don't know how to match it with user input or how to get that data if that makes sense.2nd in also little confused when I read the file and i'm storing it as a String, I don't know how to make it into an int so I can do math with it..

Comment: Item can't be a static class, since you'll have more than one item.  Divide and conquer.  Read PA2.txt to get the csv file names.  Read each csv file and create an Item instance for each item.  Once you have all your information, then get the user input.

Comment: Your code won't even compile. For example, your cost is a string, and yet the constructor passes it in as an int. There are other similar errors. Please fix your code so that it compiles, at least,

Answer (score 1):

Just to give you some help with the approach, I won't be going into detail about parsing, I think you got that covered.

Look at it from another perspective, from the input. What is the flow of the program?

- User enters required `item` and `size`
- Look if `item` is present
- User enters quantity
- Add to cart
- Repeat
- When 'done', check which Service offers lowest total price

Note: Assuming an item present in one Brand is present in all

So let's devise a Data Structure that can support this:

- We need to maintain a `Cart` for each `Service`. In the end, we can cycle through each cart and return the lowest.

  - Maintain a `Map<String, Integer>` where `String` is the `Service`, and `Integer` is the `total price`
  - Whenever an `Item` is added by the user, add the price of that `Item` to each respective `Service`
  - Eg. If Lays is added, add price of Lays in Prime to total price of Prime, price of Lays in InstaCart to total price of InstaCart, etc
- First thing you need to look up is if the `Item` is present; we can store it in a `Map`, say `itemsMap`.
- What specific properties does each item have? There's `service`, `brand`, `size`, `price`. We can store it in another `Map`, say `specificPropsMap`.
- Each `Item` can have multiple specific properties. i.e., There can be different combination of `size`, `service`, etc. for the same `Item`. So each `Item` needs to store multiple specific properties, which can be a `List`, say `propsList`.

To understand the above:

```
//Starting from the bottom-up
//To store specific properties
//Contains key-value pairs like: service = Amazon, brand = Nestle, size = 10g, price = 2
HashMap<String, String> specificPropsMap; //Has one set of specific props

//Consider an Item; it can have multiple specific properties, which we'll store as a List
//Eg: For Item = 'dark chocolate'
//specificProps1: service = Amazon, brand = Nestle, size = 10, price = 2
//specificProps1: service = InstaCart, brand = Cadbury, size = 10, price = 3
//Required: List<specificPropsMap> 
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> propsList; //Has a list of specificPropsMaps for one item

//Now we need to store all Items; it can be a Map
//Required: Map<ItemName, propsList for that Item>
HashMap<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> itemsMap;


//Initialize cart Map while parsing services
HashMap<String, Integer> cartMap; //Has initial values "Amazon" = 0, InstaCart = 0

//To find if an Item is present:
itemsMap.contains("Dark chocolate");

//Find prices from each service for that Item and size, and quantity
int reqSize = 10; //Assume req. size = 10
int reqQuantity = 5;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> propsList = itemsMap.get("Dark chocolate")
for (HashMap<String, String> specificPropsMap : propsList) { //For each set of props
    int size = Integer.parseInt(specificPropsMap.get("size"));
    if (size == reqSize) {
        String service = specificPropsMap.get("service"); //Say Amazon
        int price = Integer.parseInt(specificPropsMap.get("price")); //Say 2
        int initialPriceInCart = cartMap.get(service); //Initially 0
        int finalPriceInCart = initialPriceInCart + price * reqQuantity;
        cartMap.put(service, finalPriceInCart); //Cart price updated
    }
}

//Find lowest priced service
String lowestPrice = Integer.MAX_VALUE; //Initially set as high as possible
String lowestService = "";
for (String key : cartMap.keySet()) {
    if (cartMap.get(key) < lowestPrice) {
        lowestPrice = cartMap.get(key);
        lowestService = key;
    }
}
```

General pointers that I can think of:

**Population**: Populate all these values initially while reading from the files.

**Conversion** : Convert values such as size, price to a standard (kg, cents/dollars, etc)

**Naming** : It's better to keep it descriptive (`brand` or `brandName` instead of `bName`) 

**Error handling** : Add checks/try-catch blocks wherever necessary

Edit: Added steps. Might look a bit complex since we have some entries in the `txt` and some in the `csv`, but it's actually easy:

- Read `txt` file; you now have a `service` and a `csv` file. Thus, for each `service`(outer loop)

  - Add the `service` as a key to `cartMap` if it's not already present
  - Create a new `specificPropsMap`, add `service` to this
- Read the `csv` corresponding to that `service`. For each `item`(inner loop)

  - Store all props in the same `specificPropsMap`
  - You now have the prop `item` from the `csv`
  - Check if `item` is present in `itemsMap`
  - If present, skip to next step. If not, add `item` to the `itemsMap` as a key, with an empty `List` as value
  - Do `itemsMap.get(item)`, you'll have the `propsList`
  - Add `specificPropsMap` to the `propsList`
- Repeat for all `item`s and all `service`s.

Comment: Sorry this maybe a really stupid question, but if im getting this correctly, I can get rid of my service and item classes. The hashmap base on what I read online will be declared in main . I add the value of them thru reading the files. Then when I have all the data, base on user input It finds the lowest cost? And for your 1st Hashmap, specificPropsMap; I dont understand how to save data from two different readers.service = Amazon would come from the .txt file, and brand = Nestle would come from the.cvs file, or would I keep my service and item classes, and populate the hashmap with the class

Comment: Yup, you can get rid of the two classes. You can do it with classes too; but I recommend you focus on one way and get it running in order to get the understanding down. Here, first you read the `txt` file; in this step, you can add only the `service` property to the `specificPropsMap`. In the next step, you can read `csv` add other properties like `brand` to the **same** `specificPropsMap`(since you know this `csv` corresponds to that `service`). This would be one single iteration. Thus, for every `service`, read txt and read it's `csv` and create one `Map`, you should have the data you need.

Comment: im not really sure im doing it right or not. Im kinda getting lost when it comes to the cart and updating the price for each service.

Comment: Well you need to try it out and learn mostly. If you want, you can post your code on GitLab or GitHub and we can work on it together.